# Как перейти на другой фрагмент из класса адаптера?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня есть класс recyclerView. В нем информация, которую я должна отображать по фрагментам. Например: recyclerView содержит: id, имя, фамилию. Как я могу сделать, чтобы id отображался в первом фрагменте, затем я нажимаю на id, и во втором фрагменте я получаю имя и фамилию этого id? В моем коде,опубликованном ниже, отображается первый фрагмент. Затем,когда я нажимаю на id, перехода на другой фрагмент нет. что я делаю не так?
мой адаптер класс:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Source> sources;
    String sourceNameItem;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

   ..............................
    public  class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView sourceName, sourceId;
        public NewsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            sourceName = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
            sourceId = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceId);
    sourceId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment(sourceNameItem);
                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    sourceNameItem = sourceName.getText().toString();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceNameItem);
                    newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item clicked. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

мой первый фрагмент (где мне нужно отображать только id):

```
public class IdFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_fragment, container, false);
        restClient.startRetrofit();
        loadJSON();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        return view;

    }

    private void loadJSON() {
        final Call<News> news = restClient.getApiInterface().getNews();
        news.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
                List<Source> sources = response.body().getSources();

                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), sources);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
           
            }
        });
```

и мой второй фрагмент (куда я должна перейти после щелчка по первому фрагменту):

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
 public NewsFragment() {
    }

    public NewsFragment(String sourceNameItem) {
        this.sourceNameItem = sourceNameItem;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
 
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
       String sourceNameItem = bundle.getString("sourceName");
          textView1.setText(sourceName);

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

мои оба фрагмента расположены в аactivity_xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.company.androidretrofit.NameFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/name_fragment"/>

       <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp">
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

в макете name_fargment у меня recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
  </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

в макете details_news у меня просто TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sourceId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно увидеть из вашего кода:

```
NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment(sourceNameItem);
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

sourceNameItem = sourceName.getText().toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceNameItem);
newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item clicked. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Вы сначала осуществляете переход на фрагмент а потом пытаетесь прикрепить данные, нужно эти строки:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceNameItem);
    newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

поместить после объявления переменной фрагмента но до этой строки:

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Так же я бы вам советовал передавать данные через интерфейс так будет наверное правильнее, но я могу ошибаться. Создаем интерфейс:

```
interface OnTextClickListener {
    void onTextClick(String title);
}
```

передаем его в конструктор адаптера из фрагмента:

```
OnTextClickListener listener;
public NewsAdapter(..., ) 
   ....
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

обрабатываем клик по тексту:

```
viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    listener.onTextClick(sourceName.getText().toString());
}
});
```

наследуем созданный интерфейс в фрагменте где висит список:

```
class IdFragment extends Fragment implements OnTextClickListener {

   ...
    void onTextClick(String title) {
        // Now you can do however you want with the data here...
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

дальше в метод который будет автоматом переопределён вставляем то что вы использовали в слушателе нажатий в адаптере для передачи данных и перехода на другой фрагмент.

Comment: спасибо за совет, это вроде понятно. но не могу понять,почему при клике появляется второй фрагмент,но не исчезает первый.

Comment: поэтому и не понимаю,почему не скрывается первый фрагмент...

Comment: скажите,пожалуйста, а какой листенер передавать сюда?     `newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), sources, ????);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);` это из класса фрагмента, где списко

Comment: `this` не получится. т.к. инициадизация `newsAdapter` должна быть в методе `loadJSON()` . т е `this` тогда будет `Call<News>` а не `OnTextClickListener`

Comment: да. все как Вы сказали. Создала интерфейс. заимплементила его в классе `NameFragment` , переопределила метод `onTextClick(String title)`.В классе адаптера добавила в контструктор `OnTextClickListener listener`  в методе `onBindViewHolder` : `holder.sourceId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onTextClick(source.getName());`

Comment: прошу прощения. не NameFragmen, а IdFragment. когда я передаю в конструктор this, : `newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), sources, this)` , т к this тогда будет `Call<News>` а не `OnTextClickListener`

Comment: нет. не могу передать. `this` подчеркивает красным. и уведомление: `Required type:
OnTextClickListener
Provided:
Callback<News>`

Comment: я поправила метод `loadJSON()` (вместо создания нового объекта `Call<News>` я просто заимплементировала этот интерфейс и теперь я могу передать `this` в конструктор). но проблема таже и соталаь. при клике появляется второй фрагмент, но не исчезает первый.

Comment: да. вначале отображается первый фрагмент . затем я кликаю по йади,появляется второй фраагмент поверх первого. см. картинку: https://ibb.co/PjX5bF3

Comment: значит у вас где-то с разметкой намудрено, потому что переход осуществляется нормально)

Comment: Вы правы наверное. буду разбираться с разметкой. Спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте в активности разместить контейнер для фрагментов без обертки а фрагмент поместите в простые макеты типа linearlayout, и я думаю что простота вам поможет :)